# freeglut (./a.out): ERROR: No display callback registered for window 1

Tags: c, opengl, glut, freeglut

I'm trying to get started in learning how to make graphics with C.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {                                                   
  glutInit(&argc, argv);     
  glutCreateWindow("test");
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}
```

This was compiled with `gcc test.c -l glut`. Upon execution, the following error is printed: `freeglut (./a.out): ERROR:  No display callback registered for window 1`. What can be the cause of this, and what could be done to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to sets the display callback for the current window with [`glutDisplayFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html)  before you enter the event processing loop with [`glutMainLoop`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node14.html):

```c
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {                                                   
  glutInit(&argc, argv);     
  glutCreateWindow("test");
  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutMainLoop();
  return 0;
}

void display(void)
{
  /* ... */
}
```